# How to design a simple listview(like Android) using only html and css(without using bootstrap)

Tags: html, css, listview

I want to design a **Listview** like Android using only **Html and css** without using bootstrap.I tried with Ul and li but in this only bullet is coming.

```
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

I want like Listview like below image.
[image]
Can anyone please suggest me how to acheive this.

Comment: Be more specific and detailed with your question and did you even attempt to try it. Show your work.

Comment: @Highdef I have edited my questions.Please have a look.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
ul{
width:200px;
background:gray;
color:white;
list-style-type:none;
margin:0;
padding:0;
}
li{
border:2px solid black;
padding:5px;
}
li:last-child{
border-bottom:none;
}
li:hover{
background:red;
color:black;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>Coffee</li>
  <li>Tea</li>
  <li>Milk</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thank you so much ,This is what i was looking for. But i dont want bottom border for last item.What can i do for this to acheive. @Highdef

Comment: @ananya Updated, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Yes,Thank you so much for your help.It's working. :) :)  @Highdef

Comment: @ananya No problem :)

Answer (score 0):

you have to edit your css file like this

```
ul {
list-style-type: none;
}
```

so the list won't have bullets.